# What is $(\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt)'$?

Tags: calculus

How can I solve $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt)$?

Is there a way to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus here?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you should use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Yes, I assumed so, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x)' = f(x) = {e}^{-t^2}$, where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of ${e}^{-t^2}$, so:

$$
\int_{x}^{\infty}{e}^{-t^2}dt = F(\infty)-F(x)
$$

Now differentiate with respect to $x$, note that $F(\infty) = cte$ so it vanishes to get

$$
(\int_{x}^{\infty}{e}^{-t^2}dt)' = -F(x)' = -{e}^{-x^2}
$$

Comment: Yes he wants the derivative and not the antiderivative

Comment: It looks good I don't see where's the error though

Comment: Nm...its fine actually. +1 for my undue heckling.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not the answer to your question, as I totally missed the $'$ sign in the question! But, you may find it interesting and germane to the general issue.

Your problem is related to the [$\rm erf$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) function:

$$\textrm{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Now, we know that:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \textrm{erf}(x) = 1$$

Therefore,

$$\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\textrm{erf}(x)\implies \int_x^{\infty} e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(1-\textrm{erf}(x)\right)$$